Linking to Armadillo with CMake
I have been trying to create a small C++ project using the Armadillo library as part of learning C++ and CMake - I'm new to both. I'm using a Windows computer with the MinGW compiler. After more hours than I'd care to admit, looking at a variety of answers to questions online, for example here and here, I finally got the following to work:
File / Folder structure
ProjectDIR
 |
 +-- CMakeLists.txt
 +-- test.cxx
 +-- testConfig.h.in
 +-- thirdParty
     |
     +-- armadillo
         |
         +-- include
         +-- lib_win64

test.cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

#include "testConfig.h"

int main()
{
    arma::mat A = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0},{4.0, 5.0, 6.0},{7.0, 8.0, 9.0}};
    std::cout << "A:\n" << A << std::endl;

    std::cout << "A.t()\n" << A.t() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "A*A.t()\n" << A*A.t() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

testConfig.h.in
#define MyLatestFrustration_VERSION_MAJOR @MyLatestFrustration_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define MyLatestFrustration_VERSION_MINOR @MyLatestFrustration_VERSION_MINOR@

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(MyLatestFrustration VERSION 0.1)

add_library(CompilerFlags INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(CompilerFlags INTERFACE cxx_std_11)

configure_file(testConfig.h.in testConfig.h)

add_executable(MyLatestFrustration test.cxx)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/include)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/lib_win64)

#add_subdirectory(custom)

target_link_libraries(MyLatestFrustration PUBLIC
                        CompilerFlags
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/lib_win64/libopenblas.lib
                    )

target_include_directories(MyLatestFrustration PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

In which the armadillo/include folder is copied directly from the armadillo-14.0.3 download and armadillo/lib_win64 folder is copied from the examples provided with armadillo-14.0.3.
While this solution works for this basic implementation, I get the feeling that it isn't how it should be done. I confirmed my suspicions when I attempted to create and link a custom library which uses armadillo by adding a folder called custom to ProjectDiR containing
matrices.h
#pragma once

#include <armadillo>

arma::mat f1(arma::mat A);

matrices.cxx
#include "matrices.h"

arma::mat f1(arma::mat A)
{
   arma::mat B = A*A.t();
   return B;
}

CMakeLists.txt
add_library(MatrixFunctions matrices.cxx)

target_include_directories(MatrixFunctions INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(MatrixFunctions PUBLIC CompilerFlags)

as well as uncommenting add_subdirectory(custom) and adding MatrixFunctions into the target_link_libraries in the top level CMakeLists.txt file, then modifying test.cxx to include matrices.h and make a call to f1. This builds fine, but when attempting to run it produces the following error "The code execution cannot proceed because the libopenblas.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
So, I'd like to understand how to properly link to Armadillo using CMake and if it can be done while using the provided precompiled libopenblas.lib, or if I have to install BLAS and LAPACK or OPENBLAS; I have previously attempted to follow this route and ran into even more issues having clearly done something wrong.

"... how to properly link to..." Linking is not the problem.  The program has a runtime dependency on libopenblas.dll.  This file either needs to be in the same directory as the compiled .exe (preferred) or a directory found via the PATH environment variable.  Installing development packages does not make usually make runtime libraries available, you would create an installed to copy them.  The other option is to statically link with static builds of all dependencies.

If it's your pet project, not a request from the customer, then save yourself the trouble and don't use windows. In linux you just install OpenBLAS, LAPACK dependencies, then you can compile and install any Armadillo version with CMake, then simply use it in your project with find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED).

@RichardCritten Thank you for highlighting the actual issue. Ideally, I don't want to add the directory to the path environment variable. What I'd like is to be able to build the code on any computer. How can I ensure the libopenblas.dll is copied into the directory, or statically link? Apologies if I'm asking the wrong questions - this is new to me.

@pptaszni Thank you for your suggestion, however I'd like to be able to use and learn C++ and CMake without installing a second operating system on my computer.

To hack around this problem on windows (without providing package installer) I used this answer with DESTINATION being some bin directory in my build tree. Then you need to run cmake --build . -- install and your binaries should be ready to go.

Following the suggestions in the comments, I solved the problem by using CMake to copy the required file. In particular, I copied the libopenblas.dll to the build directory using the solution here. My CMakeLists.txt file is now
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(MyLatestFrustration VERSION 0.1)

add_library(CompilerFlags INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(CompilerFlags INTERFACE cxx_std_11)

configure_file(testConfig.h.in testConfig.h)

add_executable(MyLatestFrustration test.cxx)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/include)

add_custom_command(TARGET MyLatestFrustration POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/lib_win64/libopenblas.dll"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyLatestFrustration>)

target_link_libraries(MyLatestFrustration PUBLIC
                        CompilerFlags
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdParty/armadillo/lib_win64/libopenblas.lib
                    )

target_include_directories(MyLatestFrustration PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

in which the custom command copies the .dll file post build.
This solution doesn't feel ideal, but hopefully it will be useful to anyone facing a similar problem.

Since Armadillo is a CMake based build project you should use:
find_package(Armadillo)

ref: https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/14.0.x/CMakeLists.txt?ref_type=heads#L664-665
or unzip the source tarball archive and use add_subdirectory(thirdParty/armadillo).
(note: or use FetchContent() so cmake will download and add_subdirectory() for you...)
Then now, you have an amarillo CMake Target so you can:
target_link_libraries(MyLatestFrustration PRIVATE armadillo)

ref: https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/14.0.x/CMakeLists.txt?ref_type=heads#L579-583
note: This will also provide the necessary target_include_directory
see: https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/14.0.x/CMakeLists.txt?ref_type=heads#L586

Thank you for your answer, which looks like it could be better than the one I arrived at. However, I'm still having a few issues with your suggested approach. Using find_package(Armadillo) doesn't work for me, does this require armadillo to be installed? Using add_subdirectory(thirdParty/armadillo) does work, but doesn't link to the pre-compiled libopenblas file. Naturally this results in a number of warnings about missing required libraries, although it does build and run. Does this require LAPACK and BLAS or OPENBLAS to be installed to avoid degraded functionality?
